# jQuery datatables bundleconfig for MVC4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, nuget

Nuget installing jQuery DataTables -1.9.4 in separate folders in VS 2012. See pic.
How to bundle up them with existing bundleConfig?[image]

Current bundle I have is

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just add the appropriate lines to the .css bundle and .js bundle

**.JS**

```
"~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
```

**.CSS**

```
"~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
```